Flagging deleted post or clicking on inbox item fails and brings up an error 500 on browser console
I mistakenly told a new user that their post was not supposed to be here. I messed up. The user self deleted, which while in their credit, is because I made a mistake. This isn't fair
I'd like to make amends by flagging it for moderation attention - and when I click the flag button I get an error
Interestingly, I also get the same console error if I click on an unread inbox item - it opens but dosen't mark read unless I click on the mail icon specifically. I have the same issue on another computer, on another ISP - but the error on the console turns up and immediately vanishes.

This is the error on the page

Console output as text when I trigger this with the inbox reads as
 full.en.js?v=ba76f8465c35:1 
        
        
       POST https://meta.stackexchange.com/topbar/mark-inbox-as-read net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
clickSendMarkAsReadBeacon @ full.en.js?v=ba76f8465c35:1
(anonymous) @ full.en.js?v=ba76f8465c35:1
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
full.en.js?v=ba76f8465c35:1 
        
        
       POST https://meta.stackexchange.com/gps/event net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
(anonymous) @ full.en.js?v=ba76f8465c35:1
s @ full.en.js?v=ba76f8465c35:1
i @ full.en.js?v=ba76f8465c35:1
(anonymous) @ full.en.js?v=ba76f8465c35:1
e @ jquery.min.js:3
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3

I've tried this on a clean copy of chrome, turned off my adblocker on vivaldi, and can generally replicate it. I also run a network wide adblocker but I don't see any blocks specific to the time of test.
This is the ublock origin log around when I tried to replicate this with the inbox bug
Logger output















+3


meta.stackexchange.com
3
get
xhr
https://cdn.cookielaw.org/logos/static/ot_guard_logo.svg


+3


meta.stackexchange.com
3
get
xhr
https://cdn.cookielaw.org/scripttemplates/202312.1.0/assets/otCommonStyles.css


+3


meta.stackexchange.com
3
get
xhr
https://cdn.cookielaw.org/scripttemplates/202312.1.0/assets/v2/otPcCenter.json


+3


meta.stackexchange.com
3
get
xhr
https://cdn.cookielaw.org/scripttemplates/202312.1.0/assets/otFloatingRoundedCorner.json


+3


meta.stackexchange.com
3
get
xhr
https://cdn.cookielaw.org/consent/cb0f3c87-b769-4e66-bbaa-377f9194216d/018f2f76-a777-7516-9013-d62aa1453fd3/en.json


+3


meta.stackexchange.com
1
get
xhr
https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/401151/ivc/6fab?prg=5d612102-c7c2-4ac0-aaba-8a305d603478&_=1720137010578


+3


meta.stackexchange.com
1
get
websocket
wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/


+3


meta.stackexchange.com
1
get
xhr
https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/401151/comments?_=1720137010577


+3


meta.stackexchange.com
3
get
xhr
https://cdn.cookielaw.org/consent/cb0f3c87-b769-4e66-bbaa-377f9194216d/cb0f3c87-b769-4e66-bbaa-377f9194216d.json


+3
google-analytics_analytics.js:5
<<
meta.stackexchange.com
3
get
script
https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js


+3
||google-analytics.com/analytics.js$script,redirect-rule=google-analytics_analytics.js:5
--
meta.stackexchange.com
3
get
script
https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js


+3
||google-analytics.com^
--
meta.stackexchange.com
3
get
script
https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js


+3
googletagmanager_gtm.js:5
<<
meta.stackexchange.com
3
get
script
https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-S812YQPLT2


+3
||googletagmanager.com/gtag/js$script,redirect-rule=googletagmanager_gtm.js:5
--
meta.stackexchange.com
3
get
script
https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-S812YQPLT2


+3
||googletagmanager.com^
--
meta.stackexchange.com
3
get
script
https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-S812YQPLT2


+3


meta.stackexchange.com
1
get
doc
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/401151/flagging-deleted-post-or-clicking-on-inbox-item-fails-and-brings-up-an-error-500?noredirect=1#comment1338353_401151


+2


meta.stackexchange.com
1
get
doc
https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1338353?noredirect=1


+2


meta.stackexchange.com
1
post
ping
https://meta.stackexchange.com/gps/event


+2


meta.stackexchange.com
1
post
ping
https://meta.stackexchange.com/topbar/mark-inbox-as-read


+0


meta.stackexchange.com
1
post
xhr
https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/validate-body


+0


meta.stackexchange.com
1
get
image
https://meta.stackexchange.com/Content/Img/progress-dots.gif


+0


meta.stackexchange.com
1
get
xhr
https://meta.stackexchange.com/topbar/inbox?_=1720136904008



A quick inspection seems to suggest its not it, though since it happens on my phone, I think I'd be able to rule that out.

Is the error when you submit the flag? Or when you choose modflag option in the dialog?

When I click the flag button, I'll update

Hmm, no repro on my side. So, it might be related to your account. But the "ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT" makes me think it might be browser-related. See if disabling some addons might help. My first guess would be adblocking addons.

I can't reproduce on another site (where I have 10k reputation) - can you try what happens on e.g. HardwareRecs?

Can reproduce on a vanilla copy of chrome. I'll need to find a deleted post on hardware recs..

on the 'bright' side - other than 'one' time when it worked, I can repro at will

Got the same thing, randomly, possibly for the inbox / marking read on clicking too https://i.sstatic.net/KnvWgvNG.png I'll go poke at my PC further in the morning ._.

So it's the inverse of "works on my machine"? :P

Seems so, or there's some part of my admittedly multilayered adblock and very unique environment that's suddenly triggering this off. The only changes I made recently were a dumb switch and MAYBE running 2 ethernet connections...

https://i.sstatic.net/JphUzb92.png can repro the inbox clicking issue  on super user

@Glorfindel I believe that's called cursed :D

"Cursed on my machine" :P

.... Can repro on my phone... So just cursed, and the phone has neither AdBlock options my main system has

I raise flags on deleted posts on a irregular basis, both through the normal SE website endpoints and SE API. I have not experienced this issue (i.e., it's worked fine for me).It has worked every time I've done it over the last few/several years, including just now. In other words, doing this is something that normally works fine and just worked for me.

@Makyen or you could just say you can't reproduce it... ;) Anyway, no repro here, I just flagged a deleted post, and it went through just fine. (including retracting the flag.)

@JourneymanGeek anyway, this is possibly related to your account, maybe because you were a mod? Can't really know.

hm. I DO have another account

And... I can replicate the inbox bug on aibobot BUT there's no errors in the console. Colour me confused
